# Converting XML to JSON

Tags: json, xml, abap

I'm trying to convert an XML file into an internal table of type `String`.
Is there a function module to convert XML data to JSON format?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Google obviously not, because then you would have found some very valuable information.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP obviously didn't bother searching for an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I can tell, there's no standard function module or method call that will automatically convert XML to JSON. If you have just one file, there's a few converters online. If you *must* solve this problem with ABAP, you're going to have to cook up your own solution or hack some example program online.

If you choose to write a program yourself, consider creating a transformation in the `STRANS` transaction to convert your XML data into [JSON-XML](https://help.sap.com/http.svc/rc/abapdocu_750_index_htm/7.50/en-US/abenabap_json_xml.htm) data, and use a [JSON writer](https://help.sap.com/http.svc/rc/abapdocu_750_index_htm/7.50/en-US/abenjson_writer_glosry.htm) to write it into JSON.

This answer is mostly a paraphrase of [Horst Keller's post on the matter](https://blogs.sap.com/2016/08/04/converting-xml-to-json-with-abap-a-quest/). He has posted an example program, but your mileage may vary.

Answer (score 2):

Using a ABAP simple transformation or an XSLT transformation is only one option. You could also fully implement a conversion in ABAP code, e.g. with:

1. Use `CALL TRANSFORMATION id SOURCE XML <xml as string> RESULT <root node> = <itab>.` Refer to the [ABAP keyword documentation](https://help.sap.com/http.svc/rc/abapdocu_751_index_htm/7.51/de-DE/abapcall_transformation.htm)
2. Use class/method `/ui2/cl_json=>deserialize` and `=>serialize`
3. Use class cl_ixml: [see Parsing an XML document DOM-based and Parsing an XML document event-based](https://help.sap.com/saphelp_nw70ehp2/helpdata/de/86/8280ba12d511d5991b00508b6b8b11/frameset.htm)